# show users location blue point in iPhone MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am developing a custom pins in a MapView in my iPhone app.
Here is the code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id  <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {
     static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

     MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[myMapView  dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

     if (annotationView == nil)
     {
         annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
     }

    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Current Location",@"")])  {

        MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
        //pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        annotationView = pin;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *pin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pin%i.png",[[annotation imgNumber] intValue]];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:pin];//Canviar la chincheta per numero
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:button];
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    /********* Imagen a la izquierda en la burbuja *********/
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]; 
    // Set up the Left callout
    UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
    myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    // Set the image for the button
    //[myDetailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"botocorreu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *detailButton = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[annotation imgNumber] intValue]];
    [myDetailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:detailButton] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    // Set the button as the callout view
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailButton;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
     return annotationView;
  }
```

This works good but show me the users location with a red pin.
I check the "show user location" in the IB.
i would like to use the default blue point which will move it automatically when the user is moving, isn't correct?
How can i do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444109/9497800 . The code in the top of the viewForAnnotation method is simply `if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }` for Swift 5

Answer (score 22):

Add this to the **top** of the `viewForAnnotation` method:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;
```

The special user location annotation is of type `MKUserLocation` and returning nil in that case tells the map view to draw the default view for it which is the blue dot.

You can also ***remove*** these lines since they will no longer be needed:

```
if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Current Location",@"")])  {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    //pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annotationView = pin;
}
else
```

Comment: it works good, thnks. The ony thing is thaht the blue point which show the user location, makes a circle very big around him, is it costumizable?

Comment: The circle size indicates how accurate the location is (smaller means more accurate).  Not sure if this can be controlled in the MKMapView using CLLocationManager.

Comment: ok thnks. And you know how to introduce manually by code the userlocation. I need to put the user in one place. thnks

Comment: Unfortunately, the animated blue dot view is not available for your own annotation view and you can't override the map view's user location coordinates.  You can create your own annotation at a certain location but you can't make it use the blue dot animation.  You'll have to draw it yourself or take a screenshot of the dot and use that as an image in your annotation view.